# Call a function inside DOM ready

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I Have a Javascript library and unfortunately i **Shouldn't** change it .
there is a DOM Ready function and i need to call a function inside it, codes as below:

```
function ready(fn){
        if (document.readyState != 'loading'){
            console.log('fn called');
            fn();
        }
        else {
            console.log('fn loaded');
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
        }
    }   
    ready(function(){

        function hello() {
            console.log("hello world!");
        }
    });
```

then i need to call **hello** from outside of this scope, from another function like this:

```
function btnstart(){

        hello();
    }
```

how i can do this?

Comment: only way to access that function is to either return it from it's parent function's scope or assign it to some object reference, for example `window` in which case it becomes a globally accessible function. `window.hello = function hello(){console.log("hello world!");}`

Comment: Can you change the code that calls `ready()`?

Comment: Why do you need to _declare_ `hello` inside `ready`? This code is also not _calling_ `hello` within `ready`.

Comment: my problem is i can't change ready() , and in this case i must call hello() function from outside.

Comment: i said it before, hello is already inside ready() , i just need to call it. without change ready() function

Comment: You can't.  It's inside an anonymous function and that's all there is to it.  If you can't change any code then you definitely cannot run that function.  (Incidentally, it's never actually run in your code example so it may be that your example is wrong and there's a solution if you post correct code).

Comment: @hamed The only way to call hello is if you reference it somewhere. You do not need to change the ready function, all you need to change is the annonymus function that is being pased to the ready function as a parameter to expose the hello function. When you are defining hello define it as I told you in my first comment and you will be able to call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an explanation of your problem in a bit more detail. It's not an answer and I don't expect it to be accepted. It's to help you understand why you can't do what you're asking, unless you can change the existing code.

---

The problem you are facing is that you create an anonymous function that contains `hello()` and then pass that to another function.  Outside the scope of that anonymous function, `hello()` does not exist and is therefore not accessible.

Take this example...

```
function domReady(fn) {
    fn.hello();
}

domReady(function() {
    function hello() {
        console.log("hello");
    }
});
```

This creates an anonymous function and passes it to `domReady()`, which in turn references it as `fn`.  However, this will also fail as `fn` does not have a function called `hello()`.  That method would be created if you called `fn()`, but would still only exist inside that function.

What you really need to do is move `hello()` outside the scope of `domReady()` and just pass it as a reference, like this...

```
function domReady(fn) {
    fn();
}

function hello() {
    console.log("hello");
}

domReady(hello); // note there are no parenthesis () after hello, so it is a reference and not immediate executed
```

If you can change that then you can simply call `hello()` whenever you like (within the same scope).  If you cannot change that then you cannot do what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solution works properly.

Comment: Oh, okay.   I was expecting you not to be able to take anything other than an explanation.  I'm glad it helped :)